# Conflict during add to whitelist on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, vpn, circleci

I have 2 repositories. During deployment these repos I need add my CI/CD tool's IP to Kubernetes' whitelist. Sometimes when I execute both repositories in the same time I see the conflict.
One solution for this problem is to use VPN and add VPN's server IP to Kubernetes' whitelist.
Could you please tell me do you know other way to resolve the problem?
My kubernets is Google Kubernetes Engine ,
Ci/CD tool is CircleCI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CI/CD Tool CircleCI is probably provisioning to your different machines with different IPs for each build run.
You should consult this article to find the appropriate option to solve your issue: https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/115014372807-IP-Address-ranges-for-safelisting-Do-you-have-static-IP-addresses-available-

Comment: Is it possible to solve the problem on Google Kubernetes Engine side ?